# Suggestion for convolutional neural net model for large, rectangular images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My dataset consists of 384 x 512 single channel (grayscale images), and I'm trying to classify them into 6 different classes. What CNN model would provide the best accuracy, while still being reasonably efficient to run on an AWS GPU instance? I've tried the "Nielsen Net" that Michael Nielsen uses on the MNIST dataset:

[image: Nielsen Net]

The issue is my image data is too large to make this reasonable to train. I've added more convolutional layers and removed one of the fully-connected layers. I've played with various batch sizes and depths, numbers of feature maps, convolutional and pooling window and stride sizes, etc.

```
def model(data, depth, is_training):    
    # First Group: Convolution + Pooling
    net = slim.conv2d(data, depth, [11, 11], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    if is_training:
      print("1st conv out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2)
    if is_training:
      print("1st max pool out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Second Group: Convolution + Pooling
    net = slim.conv2d(net, depth*2, [5, 5], stride=1, padding='VALID')
    if is_training:
      print("2nd conv out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2)
    if is_training:
      print("2nd max pool out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Third Group: Convolution
    net = slim.conv2d(net, depth*2, [3, 3], stride=1, padding='VALID')
    if is_training:
      print("3rd conv out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Fourth Group: Convolution
    net = slim.conv2d(net, depth*2, [3, 3], stride=1, padding='VALID')
    if is_training:
      print("4th conv out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Fifth Group: Convolution + Pooling
    net = slim.conv2d(net, depth*2, [3, 3], stride=1, padding='VALID')
    if is_training:
      print("5th conv out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())
    net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], stride=2)
    if is_training:
      print("5th max pool out shape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Reshape:
    shape = net.get_shape().as_list()
    net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    if is_training:
      print("After reshape:", net.get_shape().as_list())

    # Output Layer:
    net = slim.fully_connected(net, num_labels)
    if is_training:
      net = slim.dropout(net)
      print("At output:", net.get_shape().as_list())
    return net
```

The training and validation results stop growing around 20%, after just 20 training steps or so with a batch size of 64. The loss stays constant and accuracy doesn't improve.

Comment: It it at all possible to resize the images?

Comment: Have you tried a pretrained net? To see if its your model or the input

Comment: @BCJuan I have not. I've tested my image preprocessing functions pretty extensively and am fairly confident that the input is good, but that concern has crossed my mind. Do you have any suggestions for a pretrained net that I could apply to my input here?

Comment: Almost all pretrained models require image resizing. Nevertheless, you can follow this tutorial which I think is useful to learn tf.slim and easy to use: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#0